# Adding project from github into intellij

Tags: java, android, github, intellij-idea

I know this can't be that difficult to do, but I'm having trouble adding the project from github found here: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib into my project. I have changed my build.gradle to look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:cardslib:library')
}
```

and I know that there must be some setting inside of module setting in order to do this. Does the github project need to be added as a module? or does it need to be added as a library? I need some help with this, I am not sure the correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: are you trying to change this code or just use it?

Comment: trying to use the code in my project

Comment: Post your gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as a dependency then in your build.gradle . You'll find the code to add [it here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards/library/0.8.0) and the description of [gradle dependencies here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:0.8.0'
}
```

Comment: I added this to my build.gradle, but when I try to use code from the project it gives errors that it can't find the methods I am trying to access. Are there more steps necessary to do add the github project to mine?

Comment: What exactly are the errors? ClassNotFoundException? Are they runtime or compile time?

Comment: Now the issue is that I can't get the project to compile. It says Androidmanifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tags. I still see it there, but I guess something changed so intelij doesnt see it anymore..

Comment: Have you modified it?

Comment: No. the only thing I modified was the build.gradle file. I do notice now in my /java directory there is the new package of the github project, could having 2 different packages in this folder cause an issue?

Comment: Check over your build file carefully. If you can't find a syntax error I would recreate the project. Use git or another vcs to make sure you can revert to working versions of your project painlessly.